# pushViewController doesn't work

Tags: iphone, pushviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController, I want to navigate from this view to my second view controller

```
SecondView *secondView=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
[secondView release];
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't do anything and there is no error. What I'm missing?

SOLUTION

In Appdelegate file I've added a navigationcontroller.

```
UINavigationController *navCtrlr = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navCtrlr];
navCtrlr.delegate = self;
navCtrlr.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: self.navigationController is nil, or secondView is nil, or secondView is not a view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Is your view controller already inside a navigation controller otherwise it wont work. put an NSLog on self.navigationcontroller and see what it is printing